# Fixing embedded audio to work on iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, audio

I've come to understand that the kind of embedded audio I'm using is disabled on a lot of mobile browsers -- is there any simple adjustment I can make to the following code to just get something working? I know this has been covered before but, as a newbie, I'm having difficulty applying the answers to my situation.

I've got this in the html

```
<div id = "sound"></div>
```

And this in javascript

```
function playSound(soundfile) {
document.getElementById("sound").innerHTML=
"<embed src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\"
autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";}
```

The soundfile argument is returned from another part of the script -- it's basically an ear training program.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using embed tag, try HTML5 audio tag instead. Also, check for the file format as well.

What file format are you using?

Comment: It's mp3 -- well I shifted it to the <audio> tag, but upon doing so and still having it not play, the answers I've read on this topic before came into clarity for me: autoplay is the problem, and the workarounds are few and far between these days